# Creating a 2D array of char in the shared memory c

Tags: c, arrays, shared-memory, double-pointer

I want to create a 2D array of char and share it through shared memory, but when I try to write in my shared memory I have segmentation fault, what can I do to write a string in my array

```
 int main {
            int j;
        char** shm = malloc(30 * sizeof(char *));

          for (int index=0;index<30;++index)
          {
            shm[index] =malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
          }

          int sh_id;
          int i;
          size_t sizeMatrix = sizeof_dm(30,100,sizeof(char));

          //creation ou ouverture de la file de segment partag�e
          key_t keyfile = ftok("keyFileIpc.txt",10);

          if((sh_id = shmget(keyfile,sizeMatrix,IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1) {
            perror("shmget");
            exit(1);
          }

          //on attache le segment au shm
          if ((void*)(shm =(char**)shmat(sh_id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1) {
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
          }
          //i can't write in here and i don't know why
          for (j=0;j<30;j++)
          {
            strcpy(shm[j],"i'm here");
          }
          printf("here\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `shm =(char**)shmat(...)` *reassigns* `shm`, making you lose the earlier allocations and give you a memory leak.

Comment: so if i allocate after the `shmat(...)` would my `shm` still be in my shared memory ?

Comment: More importantly, `shm =(char**)shmat(...)` sets `shm` to point to some pointers that have been stored by another process. Those pointers have addresses in that other process’ address space. They are generally not valid in this process’ address space.

Comment: Also, when you ask questions like this, you should provide a [mcve], including complete source code for two programs that can be compiled and run to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `shm` is a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), not a contiguous memory area which is what you need for your shared memory.

In memory `shm` would look something like

```
+--------+     +-----+
| shm[0] | --> | ... |
+--------+     +-----+
| shm[1] | --> | ... |
+--------+     +-----+
| shm[2] | --> | ... |
+--------+     +-----+
| ...    |
+--------+
```

That is, each element of `shm` is a *pointer*.

For a "proper" 2d array each element needs to be an *array*:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| shm[0][0] | shm[0][1] | shm[0][2] | ... |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| shm[1][0] | shm[1][1] | shm[1][2] | ... |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| shm[2][0] | shm[2][1] | shm[2][2] | ... |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| ...                                     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

As a simple solution you can use an algorithm to treat the contiguous area returned by `shmat` as an emulated 2d array:

```
char *shm;

// ...

for (j=0;j<30;j++)
    strcpy(&shm[j * 100], "I'm here");
```